# What’s the word for a multi-outlet extension cord?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for an extension cord with multiple outlets on one end (other than something like “multi-outlet/*n*-outlet/*n*-way extension cord“)? Something like [this](https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/ebfe354b-0464-49be-a648-f7457c6a7b9d_1.6d9ea2077033ac78c2eb4f5083bca941.jpeg?odnWidth=undefined&odnHeight=undefined&odnBg=ffffff). I’d almost call it a tiny power strip.

Example sentence: you call up a store and ask,

> Do you have any _________?

Or more realistically,

> Fun factoid: that kind of cord is called a _______.

Comment: Have you tried looking at what they are called in different online stores?

Comment: I _would_ call that a power strip, though it’s not exactly what you immediately think about when you hear that word. I can’t really find any feature that distinguishes this from a regular power strip, except the shape of the plastic box that contains the outlets. But then again, I’ve never seen a thing like the one in the image you link to before, so even if it did have a specific name, I suppose I’d be unlikely to know it.

Comment: @tmgr All I found were terms like I mentioned in the question and like linguisticturn mentions in his answer. Have you seen something different?

Comment: @Frungi No idea myself, and, while I see your objection to the term, I don't see anything _too_ much wrong with _power strip_. (Where I live sockets are much bulkier, so no equivalent thing really exists.) You might edit the question to say _where_ you've looked, as it will save time for potential answerers. There's also a research requirement for questions on EL&U and that might go some way to satisfying it. Have a look at [_how to ask_](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've always called that an "extension cord", and I suspect that you walk into any hardware store in the US and ask for an "extension cord" that is the first one they will show you.  There is generally an assumption that a lamp-weight extension cord has 3 outlets on the outlet end.  A heavier weight extension generally has only one outlet.

Comment: it is called... *an extension cord* (with multiple outlets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no such single word.

It's hard to prove a negative, but you'd think if such a word existed, then the industry would use it. But if you go on e.g. [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FF6J952) or [NewEgg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812119846&Description=extension%20cord&cm_re=extension_cord-_-12-119-846-_-Product), all you see is descriptive names like

*3-Outlet Extension Cord, 2 Prong Power Strip, Extra Long 8 Ft Cable with Flat Plug* 
*1 Foot 3 Outlet Extension Cord/Wire, 3 Outlet Electrical Cord* 
*3 Feet White 3-Outlet Designer Household Extension Cord*

Answer (score 2):

The common term is 2-way cord, 3-way cord, etc.

[3-way extension cord](https://www.google.com/search?q=3-way+extension+cord&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilmtb24ILgAhVHKawKHaY6CRIQ_AUIDygC&biw=1093&bih=501)

Comment: Yep, "3-way" is a common way to qualify it.  (Not to be confused with a "3-way lamp".)

Answer (score 1):

Most extension cords have more than one outlet on them. To qualify as an extension cord, the cord needs at least one, so a cord with multiple outlets is a "multiple-outlet extension cord." There's no word for that that I am aware of.